# In Stanford's NLP core API, how do I get a temporal expression range?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sutime

I want to use the Stanford NLP API to parse text and extract temporal expressions. The Core NLP package comes with [SUTime](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml), a library for recognizing and normalizing time expressions. Following the example on their site, I have easily found the expressions I want.

However, the [online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sutime/process) has a checkbox for 'include range', which is very useful to me. How can I pass this flag to the library API? I can't seem to find it in their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

After combing through the Java NLP mailing list archives, I found [this](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2014-May/005551.html) page which explains the issue. The way to pass options into the TimeAnnotator is to add properties, in this case:

```
props.setProperty("sutime.includeRange", "true");
```

I hope this helps someone in the future, maybe even myself :-)